# TypeError 'User' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django

aren't instances of class iterable in python as it is possible in java ,.,

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name =  models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ref_num = models.IntegerField()



ref_list = [2,3]
user_list = [User(first_name='abc',ref_num=1)]

for ref in ref_list:
    user_list.extend(User(first_name='abc',ref_num=ref))
```

but getting error as :

TypeError 'User' object is not iterable

Comment: Use `.append` not `.extend`...

Comment: To elaborate, ``extend`` takes the contents of a list, item for item, and ``append``s them to another list. ``append`` adds an item to the end of a list. Therefore, ``extend`` expects to get a ``listlike`` as its input, whereas ``append`` will take anything.

Comment: @aruisdante thanx for detailed explaination on append's behaviour...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add a *single* instance of an object, then you can use `.append`, but in this case you may as well build a generator and `.extend` the list, eg:

```
ref_list = [2,3]
user_list = [User(first_name='abc',ref_num=1)]

user_list.extend(User(first_name='abc', ref_num=ref) for ref in ref_list)
```

Remember though, that unless you `.save()` those model objects, they won't persist in your DB.